# Asynchronous method calls from base controller - old .net project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, controller

I've inherited a .net 4.6.2 MVC project that populates viewbags from the basecontroller by making an API call from within the base controller. I need to ensure that i have a valid access token to do this before the basecontroller makes the api request.
Becuase the base controller returns void I've had some issues awaiting the call to ensure i've got a valid access token and i get the `an asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.` error.
I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed, could anyone offer me advice in this situation on how to resolve this issue or perhaps a reasonable refactor that still achieves my goal of having a valid access token not just in my controllers but within the base controller.

I've tried the following:

```
  var accessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProvider();
  var task = accessTokenProvider.AcquireAccessTokenAsync(filterContext)
      .ConfigureAwait(false)
      .GetAwaiter();
  task.GetResult();
```

but this results in a really long initial load time - sometimes throwing 500 - The request timed out.
The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

Answer (score 0):

> this results in a really long initial load time - sometimes throwing 500 - The request timed out. The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

This is likely due to [blocking on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) in an ASP.NET pre-Core application. The link is to my blog, where I explain the deadlock in detail.

> Becuase the base controller returns void I've had some issues awaiting the call to ensure i've got a valid access token and i get the `an asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.` error.

This is a "safety net" exception that means the code is incorrect. In this case, [it was probably using `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#respect-the-safety-nets), which [is a no-no](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#avoid-async-void).

> could anyone offer me advice in this situation on how to resolve this issue or perhaps a reasonable refactor that still achieves my goal of having a valid access token not just in my controllers but within the base controller.

Your best option is to go [async all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#async-all-the-way). You presumably have a new method in your base controller to get the access token; make that method `async Task` instead of `async void` and ensure the `Task` is `await`ed before the API is called.

Another option is to make all the code synchronous. Ideally, you'd have (or write) an `AccessTokenProvider.AcquireAccessToken` method that works entirely synchronously (i.e., not blocking on asynchronous code, which can cause a deadlock). If you have it entirely synchronous, then your base controller will not be terribly efficient in terms of scalability, but it will work well enough until you're ready for a proper asynchronous approach, e.g., when moving to .NET Core.

A final option may also be possible if the base controller currently calls its API using `HttpClient`: you can use a delegating handler to automatically retrieve/refresh access tokens. This is a bit more complex to implement, but works well once it's in place. If the base controller *isn't* using `HttpClient` to call the API, then this option isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I went with making my method synchronous and it seems to have worked. Not ideal, but not causing trouble anymore!